Spring Boot Batch with TaskExecutor OptimisticLockingFailureException
I use Spring Boot 3 (Batch 5) with Spring Data and Oracle Database.
I have one Job with an Item Reader and a Writer (without a processor)
Everything is working fine, Now to make job process fast, want to add taskExecutor
and added
 @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10); 
        return taskExecutor;
    }

.taskExecutor(taskExecutor())

But after run couple of threads succsfully ,job is failing with error.
OptimisticLockingFailureException Attempt to update step execution after id= with wrong version (1)

